# Simple select query not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
PROVINCE -- varchar(25)
```

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE PROVINCE='Bakersfield'
```

Returns empty resultset when entries with Bakersfield as province exist

I am pretty unsure as to why. When I remove the `WHERE` it works.

BTW I am running this in phpmyadmin, where it lets one execute SQL statements

In phpmyadmin it shows ... beneath the equals sign. I am not sure why. That may be a hint.

Comment: What returns `SELECT * FROM listings WHERE PROVINCE like '%Bakersfield%'`?

Comment: I am not using any php here, executing through phpmyadmins interface

Comment: Can you reproduce this on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: SELECT * FROM listings WHERE PROVINCE like '%...%' Works, but I worry it is slower. Also I actually need it to be exactly =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you equal `=` to [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE PROVINCE LIKE 'Bakersfield'
```

This should solve your issue. If you want to find places that includes your string simply surround it with wildcards `%..%`

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE PROVINCE LIKE '%Bakersfield%'
```

Comment: Okay, but I understand that that comes at the cost of speed?

Comment: @amaranthist what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

If

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE PROVINCE like '%Bakersfield%'
```

works for you then you have spaces in your data. You can remove them with

```
update listings
set PROVINCE = trim(PROVINCE)
```

See [TRIM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

After that you should check your code where you insert the data. Check why there are spaces inserted and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE PROVINCE='Bakersfield'
```

There is no point the abpve query doesnt work if the follwing case is not the problem.

1) If case is the prob then use upper or lower

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE upper(PROVINCE)=upper('Bakersfield');
```

2) If extra space is the problem use replace or Trim

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE replace(PROVINCE,' ','') ='Bakersfield'
```

There might be sum other seniario if not then use "Like " key word as suggested by others. :)

Comment: Some provinces have spaces in their names in the database!